# How to get file upload completed count when multiple files are uploading from alamofire?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I got data to show in progress bar but how to get the count of the completed file?. The code below doesn't work.

```
upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
    print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)") // worked
    print("Number of uploaded file \(upload.uploadProgress.fileCompletedCount) \(progress.fileCompletedCount)") // always nil
})
```

please help me.